# Sizeof does not return same result in function

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I've been trying to find length of an array in C++ and wanted to make it as a function, but even if arrays are reference type `sizeof` function does not return same result as ran in
main.

The code below returns the correct result which I need.

```
int main(){
    int arr[] = {3, 71, 223, 696, 21, 453, 231, 422, 22, 32};
    int max = arr[0];
    uint length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
    std::cout << "Length: " << length << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `Length: 10`, it's OK.

But if I try to make it a function, here's the example

```
uint getLength(int *arr){
    return sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
}

int main(){ 
    int arr[] = {3, 71, 223, 696, 21, 453, 231, 422, 22, 32};
    std::cout << "Length: " << getLength(arr) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It returns `2`, therefore the unexpected output is `Length: 2`

What's causing this situation?

---

I found the reasonable explanation.

Firstly, I didn't know that C++ does not allow passing arrays completely.

Related to, if parameter is given as integer pointer, `sizeof(arr)` is constantly having value as `8` (remember integer pointer size) and `sizeof(*arr)` is `4` (remember integer size), because it points to first element of array.

Comment: Unrelated but I have seen this idiom to find the length a lot [`template<typename T, size_t N> size_t length(T(&)[N]){ return N; }`](https://godbolt.org/z/oMsKdjrz8)

Comment: `int*` is a pointer. Full stop. Yes, in the code in the question, `arr` points at the first element of an array, but that doesn't make it an array.

Comment: Yes, I found the reason yesterday and it's as you @Pete Becker explained.